# Xcode mixing RTL and LTR (Hebrew and English) for strings

Tags: iphone, nsstring, hebrew

I would like to initialize a set of string with hebrew chars like this:

```
   NSString *hebStr = @" <some hebrew> ";
```

The problem i am having is when I type the "some hebrew" in Xcode it comes out as "werbeh emos" Left-to-Right (LTR) instead of Right-to-Left (RTL).

How do I tell Xcode that what I want for that string only is RTL?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377836/right-to-left-ui-in-iphone-hebrew

Comment: Thanks, but does not really answer my question.

Comment: What are you doing to render the text now that's failing? (Or is this the XCode IDE that's failing?)